# Test InputStream with Junit

Tags: java, junit, inputstream

I'm trying to test a function "DataFeatures" in my class "UserInput".

It doesn't matter what arguments I give in the test, It always pass.

**Fields and constructor**

```
public @Getter class UserInput {
    FileType type;
    FileOperation operation;
    SynchronizationMethod method;
    String path;
    private static InputReader in = new InputReader();

    public UserInput() {
        // Dont need to do anything
    }
```

**Function to test**

```
    void getDataFeatures() {
    System.out.println("For encryption press 1");
    System.out.println("For decryption press 0");
    operation = FileOperation.fromInt(in.nextInt());

    System.out.println("For a file choose 1");
    System.out.println("For an entire directory choose 0");
    type = FileType.fromInt(in.nextInt());

    if (type == FileType.DIR) {
        System.out.println("For sync press 1");
        System.out.println("For async press 0");
        method = SynchronizationMethod.fromInt(in.nextInt());
    }
}
```

**My test**

```
public class UserInputTest {

UserInput UI;
private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private final PrintStream oldStdOut = System.out;
private final PrintStream oldStdErr = System.err;
private final InputStream oldStdIn = System.in;

@Before
public void initlize(){
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
    UI = new UserInput();
}

@Test
public void getDataFeaturesTest() {
    String data = "0" + "\n0" + "\n0";
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()));
    UI.getDataFeatures();
    System.out.println(UI.getOperation());
    assertThat(UI.getOperation(), is(equalTo(FileOperation.decryption)));
    assertThat(UI.getType(), is(equalTo(FileType.FILE)));
    assertThat(UI.getMethod(), is(equalTo(SynchronizationMethod.SYNC)));


}

@After
public void cleanUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(oldStdOut);
    System.setErr(oldStdErr);
    System.setIn(oldStdIn);
}
```

}

**Note 1**: FileOperation, FileType and SynchronizationMethod are all enums that get 1 or 0.

Example of SynchronizationMethod:

```
public enum SynchronizationMethod {
SYNC(1), ASYNC(0);

private int method;

private SynchronizationMethod(int meth) {
    this.method = meth;
}

public static SynchronizationMethod fromInt(int meth) {
    for (SynchronizationMethod SM : SynchronizationMethod.values()) {
        if (SM.method == meth) {
            return SM;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No constant with method " + meth + " found");
}

public String toString(){
    if (method == 1){
        return "Sync";
    }
    else if(method == 0){
        return "ASync";
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No constant with method " + method + " found in toString");
    }
}
```

}

**Solution**

The problem was in the class InputReader in the constructor function.

```
    public InputReader() {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    tokenizer = null;
}
```

The reader in this function and the Input Stream in the Junit function were disconnenct as suggested in the comments

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok, I changed it

Comment: Unrelated: I would suggest to **not** base your enum on int numbers. Enums have means to **build** constants from strings already. You are re-inventing the wheel here. You could decide to represent the enum values as lower case strings, and the code to create SYNC from "sync" and vice versa should be **much** shorter! Seriously: dont use numbers when you ask for user input anyway. Why do you want the user to remember that 0 is async. Let me him say "async" instead!

Comment: I put up an answer, but the point is: you did **not** provide a [mcve]. It is impossible for us to repro your problem - because you only have parts of the code creating the problem. If my answer helps, fine. If not: please read that link [mcve] and put up code that meets these requirements!

Comment: @GhostCat 
I see your point, but, are you saying that it better to write the the full word (async for example) and not only 1 digit/letter?
And how can I make the code shorter? (the code to create SYNC from "sync" and vice versa)
Thanks for your tips

Comment: By doing some research on existing methods that Java enums have for example. And what is more important : that the user does not make mistakes or that he he saves typing a few characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Guessing* here - your UserInput class says:

```
private static InputReader in = new InputReader();
```

Whereas your testcase says:

```
String data = "0" + "\n0" + "\n0";
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()));
```

In other words: there *might* be a disconnect. Depending on the implementation behind `InputReader` you might simply be reading from the wrong source.